# Do we have any css frameworks to make web applications for desktop first approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I came to hear about the css bootstrap framework which gives lots of components to start with initial development.

Do we have any other similar open source framework which is made only desktops as I am never gonna use this application for mobiles.

Being a back end developer, I really do not want to style each and every element on the web page.

Comment: Any responsive framework will work on a desktop. The fact they work on a mobile too is an advantage, even if you have no intention of using it.

Comment: but the design of components (like forms in bootstrap) look like they have been designed for the mobile.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that? It's not the case at all. They work just as well on a desktop machine.

Comment: Okay Rory will try it as you have said

Comment: [This question is off topic (#4)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that CSS Bootstrap is for dekstops only then please correct yourself my friend. Almost all the frameworks available in the market makes our website presentable  across all devices. As you are concerned only for Desktop view, so any framework will do your job perfectly fine. Most of the frameworks are Desktop view first (excluding Bootstrap 3 which is mobile first), so framework being responsive and heavy does not affect the speed of loading on Dekstop, as the styling for Dekstop will load  first.
Here's a link that gives 10 frameworks that are worth using(they are all responsive too as an additional benefit):
Choose the one best suited for you.
http://designinstruct.com/roundups/html5-frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/resources.html)... About responsive, just left it there. Use only the CSS classes for desktop screen and it will be done. So far I think it is the most advanced CSS framework for Apps (or back end in your case).

Comment: I just want a simple old fashioned web application, not a single page application. I just want a basic template to start with thats it.

Comment: @rockyit86 You can just use the CSS part, but not including JS and using any angular directive. So it will work like a basic CSS framework for you.

Comment: i don't know angular framework